# When I press the button, the button is not working?

Tags: java

I have created simple GUI in java to test the working of the click button. But when I press the button, button is not working.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;

public class rigotechnology implements ActionListener{
    JFrame test;
    JButton Try;

    public void main(){
       JFrame test = new JFrame("TEST FILE");
       test.setLayout(null);
       JButton Try = new JButton("TRY");
       Try.setBounds(50,50,80,80);
       test.add(Try);
       test.setSize(200,200);
       test.setVisible(true);
       Try.addActionListener(this);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
       if(e.getSource()==Try){
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(test,"hello");
       }
    }

   public static void main(String args[]){
        rigotechnology o = new rigotechnology();
        o.main();
     }
}
```

Comment: What does "not working" mean?  What would it do if it "worked", and what is it doing instead?

Comment: `JButton Try = new JButton("TRY");` <- this is not using ur field `JButton Try;`, you are creating a new local variable with the same name. Do `Try = ...` not `JButton Try = ...`.

Comment: Please stick to naming conventions, `try`, not `Try`. And avoid names which are already occupied by keywords, choose something more fitting. Also, what does it try? Why not `tryOptionButton` or something.

Answer (score 0):

In your method main() , you redefine a local JButton Try, so Try in actionPerformed is always null.

```
public void main(){
   test = new JFrame("TEST FILE");
   test.setLayout(null);
   Try = new JButton("TRY");
   Try.setBounds(50,50,80,80);
   test.add(Try);
   test.setSize(200,200);
   test.setVisible(true);
   Try.addActionListener(this);
}
```

Comment: what can I do to pop up the message hello when I press the try button?